# Autotools with Data Files

Tags: autotools

I want to distribute my source code and relevant data files using Autotools:

```
~/foo$ ls -R
.:
conf  configure.ac  dat  Makefile.am  src

./conf:
foo-pref.conf

./dat:
data.dat

./src:
main.c  Makefile.am
```

This is what I have so far. Without the ./conf and ./dat subdirectories I can get Autotools to work to set it up for a single executable file. But I want data.dat to be installed in $(prefix)/share and foo-pref.conf to be installed in the appropriate /etc directory. What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `dist_data_DATA = dat/data.dat` and `dist_sysconf_DATA = conf/foo-pref.conf` to achieve what you want. The `dist_` prefix says that those files should be distributed by distributions generated with `make dist`. The (in this case) middle part says what the target directory is: `data` for `${datadir}`, `sysconf` for `${sysconfdir}`, ... others can be looked up in the generated Makefile, if need be. Well, and the `DATA` primary says to do nothing spectacular with those files, as opposed to, say `SCRIPTS`.

Note that by default, configure will set `${sysconfdir}` to `${prefix}/etc` as opposed to the more customary `/etc`. If you want to change that, you need to call configure with e.g. `./configure --sysconfdir=/etc`.